# Append list of dictinaries from another with the same value python

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, data-structures, append

Assumed I have this :

```
List of Dict 1
[
  {
    "name": A
    "born": "London"
  },
  {
    "name": B
    "born": "Sydney"
  ...
]
```

```
List of Dict 2
[
  {
    "name": A,
    "class": 1,
    ...
  },
  {
    "name: B,
    "class": 2,
    ...
  }
]
```

I want to append list of dict 2 with particular attributes in list of dict 1, but with the lowest possible time complexity.

Like this.

```
List of Dict 3
[
  {
    "name": A,
    "class": 1,
    "born": "London"
    ...
  },
  {
    "name: B,
    "class": 2,
    "born": "Sydney
    ...
  }
]
```

Thank you guys

Comment: Both of them have the same length, right?

Comment: Sorry. The attributes "name" in list of dict 1 is "person_name". But I want to merge with the same value "person_name" and "name"

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA No. List of dict 2 is longer than 1

Comment: *reducing complexity algorithm.* - ??

Comment: tbh, I made it with for ... for. Any recommendation to get better than that? @Ram

Comment: Ok. Are they both sorted by default ?

Answer (score 1):

To do it without 2 for loops, you can use pandas which is very efficient. It should work very fast for long lists as well.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)

df3 = df1.merge(df2, left_on='name', right_on='name', how='left')

#To convert dataframe to a list of dicts
df3 = df3.to_dict('records')
```

You can choose which attributes to add as follows:

`df3 = df1.merge(df2[['name', 'class']], left_on='name', right_on='name', how='left')`

Comment: Any idea of the time complexity ?

Comment: sorry, d1 is not name but person_name. Can achieve it with different naming ?

Comment: @Axaxaxaxax I never worked wit `pandas` but I would try `left_on='person_name'`

Comment: @Matthias yes, I had tried on it. It worked. But I have a issue with response to dict.ValueError: Out of range float values are not JSON compliant

Comment: @Axaxaxaxax I'm not sure I understand. It worked but you are getting a `dict.ValueError`? Are you trying to convert the dataframe back to a dictionary? The issue must be arising since your data is incomplete. Also, given that d1 has `person_name`, you need to change `left_on='person_name'` for it to work then.

Comment: I see now. Looks like my post was edited. You should do `df3 = df3.fillna("default value")` before running `to_dict`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

> Time Complexity: **O(Len of D1 * Len of D2)**

```
d1 = [
  {
    "name": "A",
    "born": "London"
  },
  {
    "name": "B",
    "born": "Sydney"
  }
] 

d2 = [
  {
    "name": "A",
    "class": 1,
  },
  {
    "name": "B",
    "class": 2,
  }
]

d3 = []

for i in d1:
    temp = {}
    for j in d2:
        if i['name'] == j['name']:
            temp['name'] = i['name']
            temp['class'] = j['class']
            temp['born'] = i['born']
            d3.append(temp)
            
print(d3)
```

```
[{'name': 'A', 'class': 1, 'born': 'London'}, {'name': 'B', 'class': 2, 'born': 'Sydney'}]
```